# unable to install ZfcUserDoctrineORM with composer for ZF2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, composer-php

i just installed  all the packages for zend 2 and doctrine 2. I used composer. I successfully install **zend2**, **zfcUser** and **DoctrineORMModule**.

i am now trying to install **ZfcUserDoctrineORM** (which i believe is glue between zfcUser and Doctrine). i tried to install via composer but got the following message;

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm 0.1.0 requires zendframework/zendframewor                                                                                                                k 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm 0.0.1 requires zendframework/zendframewor                                                                                                                k 2.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm 0.1.1 requires zf-commons/zfc-user 0.* ->                                                                                                                 satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-user[0.x-dev].
    - zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm 0.1.2 requires zf-commons/zfc-user 0.* ->                                                                                                                 satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-user[0.x-dev].
    - zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm 0.1.3 requires zf-commons/zfc-user 0.* ->                                                                                                                 satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-user[0.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install zf-commons/zfc-user 0.x-dev
    - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm 0.* -> satisfiab                                                                                                                le by zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm[0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min                                                                                                                imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> f                                                                                                                or more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common                                                                                                                 problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

prior to the above error the system asked what  i was asked what  version constraint and i answer:  **0.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i rectified the problem by swapping

```
"zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master",
```

with

```
"zf-commons/zfc-user": "~0.1.2",
```

in my composer.json.

this is

> because  Composer is using an old version that exists in your
>   Composer cache, rather than downloading a new version. You can tell
>   it's using an old version as Composer is referring to
>   zf-commons/zfc-user 0.0.1 but the current version is 0.1.2. The old
>   version of zf-commons/zfc-user has a dependency on an old version of
>   zendframework/zendframework which is clashing with the other modules
>   that require a newer version.

i found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555158/composer-fails-to-update-with-zfc-user-doctrine-orm?rq=1)